# Multi query in FQL that isn't pulling data correctly

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-fql

I am not sure as to why my request isn't pulling correctly the data I'm seeking. I am new to FQL and not sure how to exactly incorporate the `WHERE IN` in this format. I'm trying to avoid using a facebook object.

The purpose of my query is to get the facebook `user_id`s of those who have liked on the last 100 posts.

```php
$fql_multiquery_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q='
. '"post+ID":"SELECT+post_id+FROM+stream+WHERE+source_id=6979393237+LIMIT+100",'
. '"like+ID":"SELECT+user_id+FROM+like+WHERE+post_id+IN+#postID"}'
. '&access_token=' . $access_token;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your FQL multi-query looks senseful, but why doesn't it work?

1. Don't use spaces inside your query names.
2. `#this` is not a variable (but a complete result set containing several rows), so you need to write an additional query (using `SELECT`) to get the interesting row (say `post_id`).
3. You forgot the opening curly bracket in your FQL query `{`.

**FQL query:**

> ```
> {
>  "posts":"SELECT post_id FROM stream WHERE source_id=6979393237 LIMIT 100",
>  "likes":"SELECT user_id FROM like   WHERE post_id IN (SELECT post_id FROM #posts)"
> }
> ```

[Test it.](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=%7B%0A%20%22posts%22%3A%22SELECT%20post_id%20FROM%20stream%20WHERE%20source_id%3D6979393237%20LIMIT%20100%22%2C%0A%20%22likes%22%3A%22SELECT%20user_id%20FROM%20like%20%20%20WHERE%20post_id%20IN%20%28SELECT%20post_id%20FROM%20%23posts%29%22%0A%7D#posts%29%22%0A%7D)

**PHP code:**

```
$fql_multiquery_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q={'
. '"posts":"SELECT+post_id+FROM+stream+WHERE+source_id=6979393237+LIMIT+100",'
. '"likes":"SELECT+user_id+FROM+like+WHERE+post_id+IN+(SELECT+post_id+FROM+#posts)"}'
. '&access_token=' . $access_token;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not the following:

```
$fql_query_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT+user_id+FROM+like+WHERE+post_id+IN+(SELECT+post_id+FROM+stream+WHERE+source_id=6979393237)+LIMIT+100&access_token=' . $access_token;
```

I don't see the need for two separate queries if you can use query nesting (for a reference look here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/fql/#query)

Comment: It indeed depends on the need. Multi-queries aim at saving the initial post ids as well as the user IDs.

Comment: Yes, I know, but in this Use Case it makes absolutely no sense in my opinion. The query execution should take more time and furthermore, you'll have to parse two results from Facebook as well (and you don't really need the first result).